# How to limit number of HTTP requests per IP address in IBM Integration Bus?

Tags: http, ibm-integration-bus

There's an IIB HTTP SOAP service exposed to multiple channels - the service has 4 operations and one of them is being consumed very frequently by a particular channel (less than 1 transaction per second).

Is there any way within IBM Integration Bus (broker or service level) to limit number of HTTP requests per channel (IP address) to 1 or n transactions per second?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement it manually using the standard facilities of IIB, but rate-limiting is an API management feature and best implemented using out-of-the-box features of IBM API Connect. It works well with IIB, btw.

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested above, this kind of logic should be done outside of IIB **if you need it globaly.**

On IIB level, you can configure many things, like the maximum amount of connection, but there's no logic to have this kind of pool for each users.

The best solution, in my opinion, is to use a network component specialized in this kind of logic. On my side, I've decided to implement this rule on the load balancer I have in front of my IIB server. A proxy could probably also do it.

For your specific case, **if it is the only case where you need this logic**, you can also consider creating different entry point for each application. If this is SOAP, and that the users currently calls /kimbertService/, you can consider having multiple SOAP Input node, with the following routes instead : /kimbertService/App1, /kimbertService/App2, /kimbertService/App3, and then you'll be sure that App1 will never block App2 ...

Answer (score 1):

IIB has a feature of throttling by limiting the number of messages processed through a given message flow per second.

For example, to set the maximumRateMsgsPerSec property for a message flow included in an application, you can use the following sample code:

```
mqsiapplybaroverride –b BARfile -k applicationName -m sampleFlow#maximumRateMsgsPerSec=100
```

You can also do it through workload management policies by using the IIB web user interface.

Below is the link:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bj58270_.htm

## A WORK-A-ROUND SOLUTION

The ideal solution, as others have mentioned, would be to have a API management gateway sitting in front of IIB to manage your API.

Now, a work-around solution could be following:

1) Have your main service flow duplicated, making them two different message flows. These two are your back-end flows performing the same thing but on one of them you can enable throttling.

2) Build a new router IIB flow which takes HTTP requests from consumers. This flow identifies the requester and routes it to the back-end flows accordingly.

Hope this helps.